# In zsh, where are precmd_functions defined?

Tags: zsh, function

If in zsh, I type `set` and see `precmd_functions=(_precmd_function_dostuff _precmd_function_domore)`.

Where are `_precmd_function_dostuff` and `_precmd_function_domore` defined (i.e. are they defined in a file? which file?)?

I can type `functions` to see the definitions of `_precmd_function_dostuff` and `_precmd_function_domore`, but this doesn't tell me where they are defined.

Comment: Does running `PS4='+%x:%I> ' zsh -x 2> >(grep precmd_func)` show any output?

Comment: Yes. I see `+/usr/local/etc/zshrc.d/10-xterm:20> precmd_functions+= ( _precmd_function_dostuff)` and `+/usr/local/etc/zshrc.d/80-PetaLinux:18> precmd_fucntions +=( _precmd_function_domore )`

Comment: Does `type _precmd_function_dostuff` tell you where it's defined?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Do you know what the `zshrc.d` is used for?  Also, do you know what the convention/meaning for the numbers in the filenames `10-xterm` and `80-Petalinux`?

Comment: Those sound files that are being provided by your distribution or  some packaging system that you use. They are not part of zsh. How was `zsh` installed on that system? Given the names, it may also be that those files are installed as part of different packages (like `10-xterm` from `xterm`...)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure how `zsh` was installed on that system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh 5.3 or above,

```
type _precmd_function_domore
```

should return something like

```
_precmd_function_domore is a shell function from /usr/local/etc/zshrc.d/80-PetaLinux
```

With `zsh` 5.4 or above, you can also use:

```
echo $functions_source[_precmd_function_domore]
```

When you run `zsh` with the `xtrace` option (like with `zsh -x`), it writes debugging information on stderr that shows every command it runs (not function definitions though). You can modify the `$PS4` variable (the prompt variable used for the `xtrace` output, see `info zsh PS4`) so it gives you more information like for each command that it runs, from which file and on each line the command was read from.

```
PS4='+%x:%I> ' zsh -x 2> >(grep precmd_func)
```

Would run a new zsh interactive shell instance, with stderr filtered by grep to show the lines that contain `precmd_func`.

Or with `zsh`, you can invoke that `_precmd_function_domore` function under `xtrace` and with `%x:%I` in `$PS4` to see where the function definition was read from:

```
$ grep -n precmd ~/.zshrc
192:precmd_foo() echo foo
$ (PS4='+%x:%I> '; set -x; precmd_foo)
+zsh:2> precmd_foo
+/home/stephane/.zshrc:194> echo foo
foo
```

(note the off-by-two line number here though).

Comment: When I run `type _precmd_function_domore` I just got the response `_precmd_function_domore is a shell function` without the `from` part you mentioned.

Comment: I'm def a newbie.  If you could explain what is `PS4` variable, `%x:%I` and `> >` that would be helpful too.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3731622, see edit.